# expect(page) .to have_content not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

The `expect(page).to have_content` syntax is legal according to the [capybara docs](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#querying), but it does not seem to work

I have added the spec file and the error below

```
require 'spec_helper.rb'

feature "Looking up recipes", js: true do
  before do
    Recipe.create!(name: 'Baked Potato w/ Cheese')
    Recipe.create!(name: 'Garlic Mashed Potatoes')
    Recipe.create!(name: 'Potatoes Au Gratin')
    Recipe.create!(name: 'Baked Brussel Sprouts')
  end

  scenario "finding recipes" do
    visit '/'
    fill_in "keywords", with: "baked"
    click_on "Search"

    expect(page).to have_content("Baked Potato")
    expect(page).to have_content("Baked Brussel Sprouts")
  end
end
```

Error when running spec:

```
sai@saip:~/rails_apps/receta$ rspec spec/features/search_spec.rb 
F
Failures:

 1) Looking up recipes finding recipes
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content("Baked Potato")
   only the `receive` matcher is supported with `expect(...).to`, but you have provided: #<Capybara::RSpecMatchers::HaveText:0x000000057c0470>
 # ./spec/features/search_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 9.95 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/search_spec.rb:10 # Looking up recipes finding recipes

Randomized with seed 31312
```

These are the versions of the various rspec gems

- rspec (2.99.0)
- rspec-collection_matchers (1.1.2)
- rspec-core (2.99.2)
- rspec-expectations (2.99.2)
- rspec-mocks (2.99.3)
- rspec-rails (2.99.0)

The vesion of capybara is capybara (2.4.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong version of RSpec for that syntax. The use of `expect(...).to ...` is the accepted way of writing tests in RSpec 3+.  You're using 2.99.

Your syntax is

```
page.should have_content("Baked Potato")
```

You should really upgrade RSpec.

Comment: Hmm, did a little research and discovered that `expect` should be supported starting from version 2.11 ([here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/Should.md#unification-of-block-and-value-syntaxes)). Since v3 there will be deprecation warning and plan is to disable it by default in v4 ([here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/syntax-configuration)). Or did I understand you wrong?